# My sortable divs cannot be moved to my seperate sortable, why is this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

The problem I am having is the culmination of two solutions to two problems I had in the past, which can be viewed on my page. Here is what I have so far for this http://jsfiddle.net/dRCLn/3/ the problem however has been that I cannot drag the modules from the content div to the moduledockcontent div. In addition if one were able to get this to work I have also added code which needs to hide the content but not the header of the module which enters the dock. The content then needs to be made visible again upon moving back into the main content. All this terminology will make sense once you see my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to drag elements from one element to childs of another element, you have to specify the `connectWith` setting: See this **fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dRCLn/4/**

```
function ModularMode(){
    //Add Module Settings
    $("#content").sortable({
        connectWith: ['#moduledockcontent'],
        items: '.module',
        ...
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ModularMode();
    //Add Module Dock
    $("#moduledockcontent").sortable({
        connectWith: ['#content'],
        items: '.module',
        ...
```

Comment: This helps, but I also want to content to be hidden upon being dragged from one sortable to the other, also I had tried the connectWith before, but I never had to use those brackets, why do I need them in this case?

Comment: @Ethanol722 It's possible to specify multiple connectWith targets, eg: `connectWith: ['#content', '#moduledockcontent'],`. About the content being hidden: You cannot hide text nodes using the jQuery selectors. You have to wrap the contents in a container, `<span>`, for example.